# Custom per folder user credentials

Tags: php, authentication

I have a a PHP project that requires an admin page that will allow the customer to create a folder that corresponds to a job number and assign a custom username/password for that folder.  There will then be another page their customers use to log into that folder and upload/download files.  What's the best way to handle the authentication?  My first thought was to put the username and password in a text file inside the folder and prevent the server from serving the page using .htaccess.  I'm trying to avoid touching a database for the project as I want to keep it cheap and simple.  Does anyone have any better suggestions on how to handle this?  FYI, this isn't a high security application. I doubt the customer will even spring for an SSL certificate.

Comment: I also provided an answer below with I believe could be some useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get SSL certificates for free at CAcert.

Apart from that, using .htaccess+.htpasswd is a reasonable option here.

Comment: Doesn't .htpasswd require the passwords to be hashed?  How would I generate the file from PHP?  (I haven't looked in any great detail. Apologies if there are built in PHP functions for generating the .htpasswd file or I am mistaken in my assumption.)

Comment: Nevermind.  A quick google search turned up an answer...  http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/create-password-for-htpasswd-file-using-php/

Answer (score 1):

```
> What's the best way to handle the
> authentication? My first thought was
> to put the username and password in a
> text file inside the folder and
> prevent the server from serving the
> page using .htaccess. I'm trying to
> avoid touching a database for the
> project as I want to keep it cheap and
> simple.
```

[OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) is the answer to (almost) all your problems:

- You do not have store username and password => BAD(storing passwords securily is very difficult concept).
- You don't have to touch any database, because OpenID handle authentications for you.
- openId has very friendly libraries([LightOpenID](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid) is very friendly) and is free(open-source).

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/openid-does-the-world-really-need-yet-another-username-and-password.html:

> As we continue to work on the code
>   that will eventually become
>   stackoverflow, we belatedly realized
>   that we'd be contributing to the glut
>   of username and passwords on the web.
>   I have fifty online logins, and I
>   can't remember any of them! Adding
>   that fifty-first set of
>   stackoverflow.com credentials is
>   unlikely to help matters.

I think you should be using [opendID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID)(Facebook Connect, etc) to do your authentication. I even created a little program that handles authentication a lot like stackoverflow.com does(with nice looking widget). You can demo this on my simple webhosting at http://westerveld.name/php-openid/. You can download the code(uses LightOpenID under the covers) at https://github.com/alfredwesterveld/php-openid.

---

```
> I'm trying to avoid touching a
> database for the project as I want to
> keep it cheap and simple.
```

I understand you would want to avoid touching database because if not done correctly it is going to make your code-base harder to grasp. But to scale using a database is a must and if you don't code around this concept when you have to switch(because system can't handle any longer) you will have a maintainability nightmare.

Also does a database help you with coding because it will abstract all the little details doing I/O(using database makes coding easier). Luckily you don't need to use a full-flexed database like MySQL/PostGRESQL because PHP(>=5) does compile/install [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) for you and you can just use it:

> SQLite is a software library that
>   implements a self-contained,
>   serverless, zero-configuration,
>   transactional SQL database engine.
>   SQLite is the most widely deployed SQL
>   database engine in the world. The
>   source code for SQLite is in the
>   public domain.

To abstract database away from your code you should learn about PDO to connect to SQLite. This [introduction](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) will learn you how to do(**Good read!**) this correctly.

These parts are especially important:

- `Connecting`
- `Prepared Statements` to prevent SQL-injections.

Then when you want to change the implementation from SQLite to MySQL it will be as simple as replacing `new PDO` to use MySQL instead of SQLite.

---

```
> What's the best way to handle the
> authentication?
```

Let OpenID handle the authentication and use the returned OpenID urls(unique) for [authorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization). You could store this information inside your desired database easily.

---

```
> prevent the server from serving the
> page using .htaccess
```

.htaccess could be used to prevent users from accessing certain files. Even easier would be to put these files in a location outside of where files will be served to web-browsers if possible. Off course you will have to put them inside that location if you also want users to access/download that file, but then you need to perform authorization.

---

```
> I doubt the customer will even spring
> for an SSL certificate.
```

Password theft is something I for sure don't like at all. In the past when I wasn't aware of the security I used one password for all my sites(remembering more is hard).When [Lifehacker got hacked](http://lifehacker.com/5110737/lessons-learned-from-a-hacked-gmail-account) I needed to change at least the passwords for important sites not to get hacked.  Right now I am using the excellent [Lastpass](https://lastpass.com/) to store my passwords securly and I create an unique password for every site. If you don't use SSL then stealing information(passwords) could be as simple as installing [blacksheep](http://techcrunch.com/2010/11/08/firesheep-blacksheep/). **But luckily when using OpenID(proper OpenID providers like Google, MyOpenID, Yahoo!) most of the times the authentication is done over SSL.**